# Unable to turn on recommendations in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

When I start software-center from the terminal, I get the following output:

```
2013-10-13 12:43:41,231 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-10-13 12:43:41,414 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master was not provided by any .service files'
2013-10-13 12:43:41,618 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-10-13 12:43:41,621 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-10-13 12:43:41,627 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-10-13 12:43:41,627 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-10-13 12:43:41,696 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-10-13 12:43:43,495 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 271, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-10-13 12:43:43,495 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: '<div style="background-color: #161513; width:1680px; height:200px;"><div style="background: url('/site_media/exhibits/2013/09/AAMFP_Leaderboard_700x200_1.jpg') top left no-repeat; width:700px; height:200px;"></div></div>' ('ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128))
2013-10-13 12:43:46,266 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Master was not provided by any .service files'
2013-10-13 12:43:47,452 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

When I press the 'Turn on recommendations' button, I get the following:

```
2013-10-13 12:48:26,466 - softwarecenter.backend.login_impl.login_sso - ERROR - _on_credentials_error for Ubuntu One: dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String(u'errtype'): dbus.String(u'GUINotAvailableError'), dbus.String(u'message'): dbus.String(u'Can not find a GUI to present to the user (tried with "(\'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\', \'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\')"). Aborting.')}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss')) ()
2013-10-13 12:48:26,467 - softwarecenter.backend.login_impl.login_sso - ERROR - _on_credentials_error for Ubuntu One: dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String(u'errtype'): dbus.String(u'GUINotAvailableError'), dbus.String(u'message'): dbus.String(u'Can not find a GUI to present to the user (tried with "(\'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\', \'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\')"). Aborting.')}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss')) ()
```

I'm running Xubuntu 13.10. I think I accidentally removed a wrong package.

Comment: I have same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: Same here, since Ubuntu 13, I thought the problem will go away with Ubuntu 14.04, but still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Ubuntu Single Sign-on:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sso-client
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sso-client-qt
```

Comment: They are already installed, but with my situation, still not turned on!

Comment: This answer has been downvoted, but it actually worked for me.

Comment: @MIH1406 had a point, I tried this as well and they are both already installed to the latest version. Is there any other solution? Probably something conflicting with Ubuntu Single Sign-on? or Is there a way to reset the Single Sign-on?

Answer (score 0):

This actually works for me and I hope works for someone else where the answer does not work. I ran the software center from the terminal with admin privileges:

```
sudo software-center
```

Then press Turn Recommendations On, and instead of cancelling the process without any warning, the Ubuntu One log-in page pops out and I was able to log-in.

Now, my question is, is there's any reason why the Software Center didn't have administrative privileges to execute the command? I remember I changed the password when the Heartbleed warning was sent out; It might caused this to happened, but there was no option to change credentials in the Software Center. I'm just assuming here.

[UPDATE] - This only works for me once... when I try to do the same this is what I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 338, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 141, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 74, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Just FYI... can any body help on this? or should I post this same question again explaining that the answer posted here do not solve all problems with the log in? In my case is failing to log in returning problem receiving reply from remote application. So apparently is not in my end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to confirm that raphie's symptoms also occur in 15.04 amd64. I also see the "working" animation, but Software Recommendations fails to turn on or display any selections. Single-signon-client and single-signon-client-qt are also installed, and I am able to sign on to Ubuntu Forums. I reinstalled software-center but that didn't help either. Have performed system upgrades for several successive versions; I probably should do a fresh install next time.